# Spring @Component vs @Configuration for basic configuration class

Tags: spring, annotations

I have some services that need configuration, thus these services is associated to a configuration class.

for example:

```
class ExampleService {
    @Autowired
    ExampleConfiguration conf;

    ...
}

class ExampleConfiguration {
    private String exampleProperty;

    public void setExampleProperty(String exampleProperty) {
        this.exampleProperty = exampleProperty;
    }

    public String getExampleProperty() {
        return exampleProperty;
    }
}
```

So does ExampleConfiguration must be declared as a @Component or @Configuration (or another annotation :))? And **this class does not define any bean**, it's just a basic configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the usage of [@Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) annotation. It should be used for annotation-based configuration, as opposed to xml-based configuration. And it must be used in conjunction with [@Bean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) annotation, to define beans available at runtime.

It looks like you actually want to define bean that will store some configuration properties. To autowire it, you can just mark it with [@Component](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html). You will also have to tell spring context where it could discover this bean via `component-scan`.

Comment: Oki thanks, I was not sure about that. Now it's clear thanks to you :)